# validate and post using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

I like to know how to validate and post a image upload forum using jquery.  There are only two inputs: title and image.  I need to give an error if any of this fields are empty or if the uploaded file is in a wrong format.  Here is the code I have (this is not using jquery at the moment.)

Image.php

```
<?php

$uploadDir = 'images/'; //Image Upload Folder
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']); 
    $fileName = $_FILES['Photo']['name'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['Photo']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['Photo']['type'];
    $filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;
    $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Error uploading file";
        exit;
    }
    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
        $filePath = addslashes($filePath);
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO images(title,image) VALUES ('".$title."','".$filePath."')";
    mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
}
?>

<form name="Image" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="image.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value=""><br/><br/>
<input type="file" name="Photo" size="20" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/x-ms-bmp, image/x-png"><br/>
<INPUT type="submit" class="button" name="Submit" value=" Submit ">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't check the file with jQuery, you could check that it has the right extension. To check if the fields are blank you can use:

```
if ($('#title').val() === '') {
    // error code
}
```

You could check the file extension with something like:

```
var extension = $('input[name=Photo]').val().split('.').pop();
if (extension !== "gif" && extension !== "jpg") {
    // error code
}
```

I'm not sure if you want to use AJAX to post the file, but you don't have to. If you attach your validation for the form submit event you can stop the form from submitting if there is an error, otherwise let it submit to the server.

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    var error = false;
    // error checking here

    if (error) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks how do u make it to check more then one file type. like jpg and gif

Answer (score 0):

You could validate on extension...

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
   var file = $('input[type=file]').val();       

   if ( ! file) {
       alert('The file is required.');
       event.preventDefault();
       return;
   } 

   if (file.match(/\.(?:jpeg|jpg|gif)$/)) {
       alert('Image files only!');
       event.preventDefault();
   }

});
```

...or you could validate on mime type.

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
   var file = $('input[type=file]').prop('files')[0];

   if ( ! file) {
       alert('The file is required.');
       event.preventDefault();
       return;
   } 

   var mime = file.type;

   if (mime != 'text/jpeg' || mime != 'application/gif') {
       alert('Image only!');
       event.preventDefault();
   }

});
```

Of course, you need to validate on the server too, this code is just a courtesy to JavaScript enabled users.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use jQuery validation jQuery library it has a lot of validation built in so you don't need to worry about handling multiple conditions and it's pretty easy to use.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation